# How To Show Progress Dialog After Inserting My List view Data

Tags: java, android, sql-server

How To Show Progress Dialog After Inserting My List view Data how can i use progress dialog in my code.
after inseting lisview rows values how to show progress dialog

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Connection_Class connectionClass;
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
    List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
    String cc,a,s;
    String mira,shef,session;
    String accno1;
    List<String> ppp3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView listView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    EditText almirah,shelf,accession_no;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        connectionClass = new Connection_Class();
        Button add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        Button submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        Button clear=(Button)findViewById(clear);
        almirah=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.almirah);
        shelf=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.shelf);
        accession_no=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.accession_no);
        listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.proress);


        simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),data,listview, new String[]{"A", "B", "C"}, new int[]{al, sh, acc});
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);



        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (almirah.length()==0||shelf.length()==0||accession_no.length()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Fill Full Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    String alm = almirah.getText().toString();
                    String she = shelf.getText().toString();
                    String accno = accession_no.getText().toString();
                    datanum.put("A", alm);
                    datanum.put("B", she);
                    datanum.put("C", accno);
                    data.add(datanum);
                    simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    accession_no.setText("");
                }
            }

        });



        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               submit_btn();
            }
        });

        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                almirah.setText("");
                shelf.setText("");
                accession_no.setText("");
                List<Map<String, String>> data2 = null;
                data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
             SimpleAdapter   simpleAdapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),data,listview, new String[]{"A", "B", "C"}, new int[]{al, sh, acc});
                listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter2);
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());

            }
        });
    }

    public void submit_btn(){

        if (data.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your List Is Empty Please Fill First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
//                    final ProgressDialog progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
//                    progressdialog.setMessage("Please Wait....");
//                    progressdialog.show();

            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) listView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                a = (String) obj.get("A");
                s = (String) obj.get("B");
                cc = (String) obj.get("C");

                try {
                    Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                    if (con == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in connection with SQL server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        try {
                            con = connectionClass.CONN();
                            if (con == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in connection with SQL server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } else {
                                String query = "SELECT AccessionNo FROM suigen.TransAlmiraShelf WHERE AccessionNo='" + String.valueOf(cc) + "'";
                                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                                while (rs.next()) {
                                    ppp3.add(rs.getString("AccessionNo"));


                                    StringBuilder builder3 = new StringBuilder();
                                    for (String value : ppp3) {
                                        builder3.append(value);
                                    }
                                    accno1 = builder3.toString();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exceptions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        if (cc.equals(accno1)) {
                            try {
                                con = connectionClass.CONN();
                                if (con == null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in connection with SQL server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else {
                                    String query = "UPDATE suigen.TransAlmiraShelf SET Almira='"+String.valueOf(a)+"',Shelf='"+String.valueOf(s)+"' WHERE AccessionNo='" + cc + "'";
                                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                                    stmt.execute(query);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exceptions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            String query = "INSERT INTO suigen.TransAlmiraShelf (Almira, Shelf, AccessionNo) VALUES('" + String.valueOf(a) + "','" + String.valueOf(s) + "','" + String.valueOf(cc) + "')";
                            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                            stmt.execute(query);

                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exceptions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your Data Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            almirah.setText("");
            shelf.setText("");
            accession_no.setText("");
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use AsyncTask and implement Progress dialog in onPreExecute() and dismiss PD in onPostExecute() methods

Comment: how  to use can u explain from my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try above this may help

```
 public void submit_btn(){
    AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {


        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Please Wait!!");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

            if (data.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your List Is Empty Please Fill First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) listView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                    a = (String) obj.get("A");
                    s = (String) obj.get("B");
                    cc = (String) obj.get("C");

                    try {
                        Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                        if (con == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in connection with SQL server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {

                            try {
                                con = connectionClass.CONN();
                                if (con == null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in connection with SQL server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                } else {
                                    String query = "SELECT AccessionNo FROM suigen.TransAlmiraShelf WHERE AccessionNo='" + String.valueOf(cc) + "'";
                                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                                    while (rs.next()) {
                                        ppp3.add(rs.getString("AccessionNo"));


                                        StringBuilder builder3 = new StringBuilder();
                                        for (String value : ppp3) {
                                            builder3.append(value);
                                        }
                                        accno1 = builder3.toString();
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exceptions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            if (cc.equals(accno1)) {
                                try {
                                    con = connectionClass.CONN();
                                    if (con == null) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in connection with SQL server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else {
                                        String query = "UPDATE suigen.TransAlmiraShelf SET Almira='"+String.valueOf(a)+"',Shelf='"+String.valueOf(s)+"' WHERE AccessionNo='" + cc + "'";
                                        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                                        stmt.execute(query);
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exceptions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                String query = "INSERT INTO suigen.TransAlmiraShelf (Almira, Shelf, AccessionNo) VALUES('" + String.valueOf(a) + "','" + String.valueOf(s) + "','" + String.valueOf(cc) + "')";
                                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                                stmt.execute(query);

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exceptions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
          return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            progressDialog.cancel();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your Data Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            almirah.setText("");
            shelf.setText("");
            accession_no.setText("");
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());

        }
    };
    task.execute();

}
```